# Python adding a string to a match list with multiple items

Tags: python

The code I am working on is retrieving a list from an HTML page with 2 fields, URL, and title...

The URL anyway starts with `/URL....` And I need to append the "http://website.com" to every returned vauled from a `re.findall`.

The code so far is this:

```
bsoup=bs(html)
tag=soup.find('div',{'class':'item'})
reg=re.compile('<a href="(.+?)" rel=".+?" title="(.+?)"')
links=re.findall(reg,str(tag))
*(append "http://website.com" to the href"(.+?)" field)*
return links
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1459669 Please, use beautiful soup to find the links!

Comment: @CrazyPython Unless you want to summon Cthulhu.

Comment: @timgeb You never know, he might want to summon him. Then we'll need it migrated to StackExchange Skeptics or Worldbuilding...

Comment: Are you going to accept the answer or what? It's like saying "thank you" because it awards reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
for link in tag.find_all('a'):
    link['href'] = 'http://website.com' + link['href']
```

Then use one of these output methods:

`return str(soup)` gets you the document after the changes are applied.

`return tag.find_all('a')` gets you all the link elements.

`return [str(i) for i in tag.find_all('a')]` gets you all the link elements converted to strings.

Now, don't try to parse HTML with regex while you *have a XML parser already working.*

Comment: Oops, my bad. Reversed order of URL appendage.